# Tensorflow model pruning gives 'nan' for training and validation losses

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, model

I'm trying to prune a base model that consists of several layers on top of a VGG network. It also contains a user-defined layer named `instance_normalization`. For pruning to be successful, I've defined the `get_prunable_weights` function of this layer as follows:

```
### defined for model pruning
    def get_prunable_weights(self):
        return self.weights
```

I used the following function to obtain a to-be-pruned model structure using a base model named `model`:

```
def define_prune_model(self, model, img_shape, epochs, batch_size, validation_split=0.1):
        num_images = img_shape[0] * (1 - validation_split)
        end_step = np.ceil(num_images / batch_size).astype(np.int32) * epochs

        # Define model for pruning.
        pruning_params = {
            'pruning_schedule': tfmot.sparsity.keras.PolynomialDecay(initial_sparsity=0.5,
                                                                    final_sparsity=0.80,
                                                                    begin_step=0,
                                                                    end_step=end_step)
        }

        model_for_pruning = prune_low_magnitude(model, **pruning_params)

        model_for_pruning.compile(optimizer='adam',
                    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                    metrics=['accuracy'])

        model_for_pruning.summary()

        return model_for_pruning
```

Then, I wrote the following function to perform training on this pruning model:

```
def train_prune_model(self, model_for_pruning, train_images, train_labels,
                     epochs, batch_size, validation_split=0.1):
    callbacks = [
    tfmot.sparsity.keras.UpdatePruningStep(),
    tfmot.sparsity.keras.PruningSummaries(log_dir='./models/pruned'),
    ]
    model_for_pruning.fit(train_images, train_labels,
                batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=validation_split,
                callbacks=callbacks)
    return model_for_pruning
```

However, when training, I found out that the training and validation losses were all `nan`, and the final model prediction output was totally zero. However, the base model that passed to `define_prune_model` has successfully trained and predicted correctly.

How can I solve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to pinpoint the issue without more informations. In particular, can you please give more detail (preferably as code) about your custom `instance_normalization` layer ?

Assuming that the code is fine: Since you mentioned that the model trains correctly without pruning, could it be that those pruning parameters are too harsh ? After all, those options set `50%` of the weights to zero right from the first learning step.

Here is what I would try:

- Experiment with a lower level of sparsity (especially `initial_sparsity`).
- Start to apply pruning later during the training (`begin_step` argument of the [pruning schedule](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/api_docs/python/tfmot/sparsity/keras/PolynomialDecay)). Some even prefer to train the model once without applying pruning at all. Then re-train again with `prune_low_magnitude()`.
- Only prune at some steps, giving time for the model to recover between prunings (`frequency` argument).
- Finally should it still fail, the usual cures when encountering nan losses: reduce the learning rate, use regularization or gradient clipping, ...